# Looking at implementing a user point shop system

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for advice that will hope myself and hopefully others.
Basically I have a site I am working on that has a user login system, and a topic system similar to a forum, I am looking at adding a new feature and I am looking for some experienced advice behind the logic in what I am trying to do.

**The Goal**

The goal is when a user makes a post, it stores a point in a "points" field in the user table for that particular user, I am now looking for a way so that when say a user has 100 points, they can exchange for a feature, such as a profile page or background image on their profile.

My question is how would be the best way to implement this structure?
ie.

```
**USERS table**

user_id
username
points

**FEATURE table**
feature_id
feature_name

**FEATURE USER table**
feature_id
user_id
```

Any suggested advice with the logic behind a system like this would be much appreciated!

Comment: i see nothing obviously wrong with the structure above, it does not show any tracking of when and how points where accumulated, but that may not be an issue for you.

Comment: I am always a fan of adding two things, last modified information and record_Status just to ensure that if your application needs a delete and you want to retain data in the db to allow an undelete, then you can use the record status.... other than the comment above and mine your basic structure is fine

Comment: thanks for the quick response, my thinking is say you have built up 100 points, you can see "100 points" under your profile, then have a page that allows you to pick a feature for 100 points or less, deduct from the points column in the user table, then insert into  feature user "1" "1" if that is both your user_id and the feature id

Comment: sounds like plan, start codding :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are few things missing that will make your life easier down the road, including:

- unique ids in each table (including 'feature_user').
- a status
  and/or start/stop dates in the feature table, so you can stop
  offering a particular feature down the road.  The nice thing about
  start/stop dates is that you can set them in advance (imagine a
  promotion that ends at midnight on new years - do you want to be
  awake??).
- redemption_date and redemption_points columns in the
  feature_user table.  This is a poor man's accounting system, which
  you'll eventually want.

Depending on how serious points are to your site, you might want to implement a real accounting system for them (credits/debits).

Hope that helps.